# Dependency-Check-Maven Plugin Scanning Sibling project dependency also

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I am using Dependency-Check-maven plugin in multi-pom project. At time of report generation it scanning jars of not only mine but others also. I want to scan only jars listed my project.

This is plugin in my parent pom.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.owasp</groupId>
    <artifactId>dependency-check-maven</artifactId>
    <version>6.3.1</version>
    <configuration>
    <assemblyAnalyzerEnabled>false</assemblyAnalyzerEnabled>
    <nugetconfAnalyzerEnabled>false</nugetconfAnalyzerEnabled>
    <nuspecAnalyzerEnabled>false</nuspecAnalyzerEnabled>
    <retireJsAnalyzerEnabled>false</retireJsAnalyzerEnabled>
    <jarAnalyzerEnabled>true</jarAnalyzerEnabled>
    <failBuildOnAnyVulnerability>false</failBuildOnAnyVulnerability>
    <outputDirectory>target/build/docs</outputDirectory>
        <scanSet>   
            <fileSet>
                <directory>target/build/lib/third_party</directory>
            </fileSet>
        </scanSet>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                   <goal>check</goal>
                    <goal>aggregate</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

My jars which need to be scan are present in target/build/lib/third_party folder.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It is scanning extra jars those are not listed in my folder @AidanDonnelly